# CodeIgniter creating MY_Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller, extends

How can i create MY_Controller. Where is right place to put this file, i put it in core, folder, and i add into autoload file
code

```
function __autoload($class)
{
 if(strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0)
 {
  @include_once( APPPATH . 'core/'. $class . EXT );
 }
}
```

then i created MY_Controller

```
class My_Controller extends CI_Controller
{

    public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->view('view_header');
        $this->load->view('includes/nav_home');
        $this->load->view('view_home');
        $this->load->view('view_footer');   

    }
}
```

but i keep getting error

Class 'MY_Controller' not found in C:\wamp\www\vezba\application\controllers\pages.php on line 4

i called MY_Controller in file

```
class Pages extends MY_Controller 
{    
   function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
  }

}
```

Where could be problem??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Double check the case on your class name and file name.

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
```

Notice how `MY_` is all upper-case.  Make sure this file is saved as `application/core/MY_Controller.php`, again note the case.

CodeIgniter should auto-load this file for you.

Docs: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html

P.S. Check the `$config['subclass_prefix']` option in your `application/config/config.php` file.

Comment: i put this files in system core not aplication core

Comment: You shouldn't be modifying the `system` folder.  That's why `application/core` exists.  So you can extend/replace files without touching the system files.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the autoloading functionality. Codeigniter will automatically load My_Controller as long as it's in your application/core directory.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to autoload your class, the framework will do it for you. In your case check the config file whether the subclass_prefix is 'MY_'. Eg; $config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';
Put your class in application/core. Make sure the class name and the file name is the same.